# How can I break a string with <some value> tags into a Map collection and assigned it boolean values if it is or not?

Tags: java, string

I have a string like this one:

```
String subject = "Subject Line: <abc> <def> <ghi> some text <hjk>";
```

And I want to break it and put values into a map collection like this:

```
Map<String, Boolean> maps = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
maps.put("Subject Line: ", false); 
maps.put("abc", true); 
maps.put("def", true);
maps.put("ghi", true); 
maps.put(" some text ", false); 
maps.put("hjk", true);
```

Comment: You might be better off posting an actual example

Comment: I've edited your code to make it more readable and kindly ask you to do that yourself next time. If it's hard to read your post it's harder to help and easier to down vote or vote to close the question. That being said, there's a lot of things missing, e.g. based on what logic should the string be split and get flags assigned? Do you want to extract something like tags? Could tags include whitespace? Could they include attributes, e.g. look like `"<tag attr='<hello>'>"`?

Comment: As this looks like homework/learning exercise- what have you tried and failed?

Comment: It is not homework/learning exercise: it is for a commercial project for a big company. I know how to recognize <> like this:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
while (m.find()) {
    c.put(m.group(), true);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your regex a little you can do it using your code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^>]*)<([^>]+)>"); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(subject);
    
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String nonTag = m.group(1);
        String tag = m.group(2);
        
        if( !nonTag.isBlank() ) {
            c.put(nonTag, false);
        }
        
        if( !tag.isBlank() ) {
            c.put(tag, true);
        }
    }
```

You basically look for tags and any optional "non-tag" text before. Any text after the last tag would be a final key with the value `false`.

I'd have to dig some more into the `Matcher` API but it seems there is no easy way to get the "remainder" since `appendTail()` etc. don't work without any previous call to `appendReplacement()`. Thus you'd need to extend your loop a little:

```
int lastMatch = 0;
while(m.find()) {
  ...
  lastMatch = m.end();
}

if( lastMatch < subject.length() ) {
   c.put( subject.substring(lastMatch), false );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! It seems to work!!! :)
Just one more question: I actually want to make empty spaces between <> as items that are nontag... how can I modify regex pattern to NOT ignore empty spaces?
I don't have regex skills.

So in the map I should also have:
maps.put(" ", false);

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Something like `"< >"` should be reported as a key but not as a tag? That should be easy enough since all you'd need to do is check the value of `tag` inside the loop (a combination of `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` should do the trick). Btw, getting some regex skills is definitely worth it.

Comment: I just removed both isBlank() and then everything works as expected. Thank you so much!!! ;)

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I break this string like this one:
```
"something something something <PY Begin> thought <PY End>.
```
So I can have the next list items:

```
Map<String, Boolean> maps = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
maps.put("something something something ", false); 
maps.put("PY Begin", true); 
maps.put(" thought ", false);
maps.put("PY End", true); 
maps.put(".", false); 
```

So the item 5 "." is missing... I don't know why!?

Comment: @Navuhodonosor it's hard to tell without seeing your code but using the one I posted here and the string you provided it works. Did you check for any left-over parts in your input string after the loop like I described in the bottom half of the answer?